# Running pyshark (tshark) in a container: TShark not found

Tags: python, docker, wireshark, container

I'm trying to run pyshark (which uses tshark) inside a docker container, but without success so far. I already stumbled upon different problems using centos in a containter, in combination with pyshark (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52155191/tshark-running-on-centos-inside-docker-operation-not-permitted-usr-sbin-dump), but due to a lack of response I decided to give Ubuntu a try. It works a bit better, so it seems, but I still get some errors. Hopefully someone can help me out over here. This is the code I wrote:

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  tshark:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    container_name: tshark
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

# add a non-root user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash shark

# tell environment we're not able to respond to quesitons
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# install python and curl packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python3.6 && \
    apt-get install -y python3-distutils && \
    apt-get install -y curl

# fix pip
RUN curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py && \
    /usr/bin/python3.6 get-pip.py && \
    rm get-pip.py

# install pyshark and wireshark
RUN apt-get install -y libcap2-bin wireshark && \
    pip install pyshark

# add group wireshark, add shark user and give right permissions
RUN groupadd wireshark && \
    usermod -aG wireshark shark && \
    newgrp wireshark && \
    chgrp wireshark /usr/bin/dumpcap && \
    chmod 750 /usr/bin/dumpcap && \
    setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip /usr/bin/dumpcap

RUN dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# switch to user shark
USER shark

CMD [ "python3", "process.py" ]
```

My process.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 
import pyshark

capture = pyshark.LiveRingCapture(interface='eth0')

for packet in capture.sniff_continuously(packet_count=5):
    print('Just arrived:', packet)
```

This is the result I keep getting after running `docker-compose up --build`:

```
tshark_1  | [2018-09-04 08:37:01.970432] DEBUG: LiveRingCapture: Creating Dumpcap subprocess with parameters: /usr/bin/dumpcap -q -P -i eth0 -w -
tshark_1  | [2018-09-04 08:37:01.973137] DEBUG: LiveRingCapture: %s subprocess created
tshark_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
tshark_1  |   File "process.py", line 7, in <module>
tshark_1  |     for packet in capture.sniff_continuously(packet_count=5):
tshark_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 207, in _packets_from_tshark_sync
tshark_1  |     tshark_process = existing_process or self.eventloop.run_until_complete(self._get_tshark_process())
tshark_1  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 468, in run_until_complete
tshark_1  |     return future.result()
tshark_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyshark/capture/live_capture.py", line 92, in _get_tshark_process
tshark_1  |     tshark = await super(LiveCapture, self)._get_tshark_process(packet_count=packet_count, stdin=read)
tshark_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 361, in _get_tshark_process
tshark_1  |     parameters = [self._get_tshark_path(), '-l', '-n', '-T', output_type] + \
tshark_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 345, in _get_tshark_path
tshark_1  |     return get_process_path(self.tshark_path)
tshark_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyshark/tshark/tshark.py", line 98, in get_process_path
tshark_1  |     'Search these paths: {}'.format(possible_paths)
tshark_1  | pyshark.tshark.tshark.TSharkNotFoundException: TShark not found. Try adding its location to the configuration file. Search these paths: ['C:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\tshark.exe', '/usr/local/sbin/tshark', '/usr/local/bin/tshark', '/usr/sbin/tshark', '/usr/bin/tshark', '/sbin/tshark', '/bin/tshark']
tshark_1  | Capturing on 'eth0'
tshark_1  | dumpcap: The capture session could not be initiated on interface 'eth0' (You don't have permission to capture on that device).
tshark_1  | Please check to make sure you have sufficient permissions, and that you have the proper interface or pipe specified.
```

**EDIT:**

Seems that ubuntu indeed requires installing tshark instead of wireshark, so I updated the Dockerfile a bit which results in a different error:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

# add a non-root user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash shark

# tell environment we're not able to respond to quesitons
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# install python and curl packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python3.6 && \
    apt-get install -y python3-distutils && \
    apt-get install -y curl

# fix pip
RUN curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py && \
    /usr/bin/python3.6 get-pip.py && \
    rm get-pip.py

# install pyshark and wireshark
RUN apt-get install -y libcap2-bin tshark && \
    pip install pyshark

# add group wireshark, add shark user and give right permissions


RUN dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# switch to user shark
USER shark

CMD [ "python3", "process.py" ]
```

error:

```
tshark_1  | [2018-09-04 08:57:31.369160] DEBUG: LiveRingCapture: Creating Dumpcap subprocess with parameters: /usr/bin/dumpcap -q -P -i eth0 -w -
tshark_1  | [2018-09-04 08:57:31.371591] DEBUG: LiveRingCapture: %s subprocess created
tshark_1  | [2018-09-04 08:57:31.372154] DEBUG: LiveRingCapture: Creating TShark subprocess with parameters: /usr/bin/tshark -l -n -T pdml -r - -b filesize:1024 -b files:1 -w /tmp/pyshark.pcap -P
tshark_1  | [2018-09-04 08:57:31.374377] DEBUG: LiveRingCapture: %s subprocess created
tshark_1  | Capturing on 'eth0'
tshark_1  | dumpcap: The capture session could not be initiated on interface 'eth0' (You don't have permission to capture on that device).
tshark_1  | Please check to make sure you have sufficient permissions, and that you have the proper interface or pipe specified.
tshark_1  | tshark: Multiple capture files requested, but a capture isn't being done.
tshark_1  | [2018-09-04 08:57:31.595492] DEBUG: LiveRingCapture: EOF reached (sync)
tshark_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
tshark_1  |   File "process.py", line 7, in <module>
tshark_1  |     for packet in capture.sniff_continuously(packet_count=5):
tshark_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 229, in _packets_from_tshark_sync
tshark_1  |     self.eventloop.run_until_complete(self._cleanup_subprocess(tshark_process))
tshark_1  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 468, in run_until_complete
tshark_1  |     return future.result()
tshark_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 399, in _cleanup_subprocess
tshark_1  |     % process.returncode)
tshark_1  | pyshark.capture.capture.TSharkCrashException: TShark seems to have crashed (retcode: 1). Try rerunning in debug mode [ capture_obj.set_debug() ] or try updating tshark.
tshark_1  | Exception ignored in: <bound method Capture.__del__ of <LiveRingCapture (0 packets)>>
tshark_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
tshark_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 411, in __del__
tshark_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 402, in close
tshark_1  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 468, in run_until_complete
tshark_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 406, in _close_async
tshark_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 399, in _cleanup_subprocess
tshark_1  | pyshark.capture.capture.TSharkCrashException: TShark seems to have crashed (retcode: 1). Try rerunning in debug mode [ capture_obj.set_debug() ] or try updating tshark.
```